# Large-sized HTML Table or <p> elements for quicker page load

Tags: html

I have a HTML table on a webpage which has around 2,500 rows.
Standard HTML elements used - `th, tr, td` with alternate row colors changing for better readability.

However, since the table size is large (~2,500 rows), it appears to be loading slow in the browser.

**Will the speed of page loading improve if I switch from HTML table to `<p>` elements for each row?**

I did the following to test:

Built two test pages with exactly similar data and used HTML table in one, and `<p>` elements in another. I then tested both the versions with Google Dev PageSpeed tool (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

Unfortunately, no big difference is observed in the score on PageSpeed tool. I doubt if that test is realistic as along with HTML schema, it may take several other unknowns in consideration for arriving at test results.

**Any inputs on whether switching from HTML table (`th, tr, td` tags) to `<p>` tags for displaying each row will improve the page loading speed?** Or any other thoughts for improving page loading time?

I dont want to use javascript, as it further slows it down. Only HTML tags.

Comment: You will have to use javascript and build lazyload system

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Ajax and load data part by part. Also, you can use this resource to make ajax datatables:
[Ajax sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax#:%7E:text=DataTables%20has%20the%20ability%20to,of%20the%20JSON%20data%20source.)